# Quitar Hover con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, ccs

Quisiera saber si con javascript o jquery puedo retirar la pseudo clase Hover de algún selector css..Lo que tengo es un menú desplegable que al pasar el hover por un "li" se despliega.. Quisiera colocar un botón que al darle click quite el Hover de ese "li" y ya no aparezca el desplegable -..sera posible ?

agrego html

```
<li class="hidden_tablet"><span><a href="#0">Capacitación</a></span>
  <ul id="grid_home2" >
    <li>
      <a href="#0" class="img_container">
        <img src="img/gp.png" alt="">
        <div class="short_info">
          <h3 class="mrmago"><strong>Gestión Pública</strong></h3>
          <!-- <div><span class="btn_1 rounded">Ir al curso</span></div> -->
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#0" class="img_container">
        <img src="img/derecho.png" alt="">
        <div class="short_info">
          <h3 class="mrmago"><strong>Derecho</strong></h3>
          <!-- <div><span class="btn_1 rounded">Ir al curso</span></div> -->
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    ...

  </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.main-menu ul li:hover > ul {
  padding: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Con jquery se puede quitar ese hover al darle click algun boton ?

Comment: Ya lo agregue aprte del html y css

Answer (score 1):

Podes recorrer todas las plantillas de estilos con [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList), una vez que encontrás la regla que deseas dentro de [`styleSheet.cssRules`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRuleList) la borras con [`styleSheet.deleteRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule)

```js
let quitarCSS = function() {
  for (let n = 0; n < document.styleSheets.length; n++) {
    let styleSheet = document.styleSheets[n];
    for (let i = 0; i < styleSheet.cssRules.length; i++) {

      if ( ".main-menu ul li:hover > ul" === styleSheet.cssRules[i].selectorText ) {
        // console.log(styleSheet.cssRules[i]);
        styleSheet.deleteRule(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.main-menu ul li>ul {
  visibility: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.main-menu ul li:hover>ul {
  padding: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick=quitarCSS()>quitar CSS</button>
<nav class=main-menu>
  <ul>
    <li class="hidden_tablet"><span><a href="#0">Capacitación</a></span>
      <ul id="grid_home2">
        <li>
          <a href="#0" class="img_container">
            <img src="img/gp.png" alt="">
            <div class="short_info">
              <h3 class="mrmago"><strong>Gestión Pública</strong></h3>
              <!-- <div><span class="btn_1 rounded">Ir al curso</span></div> -->
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#0" class="img_container">
            <img src="img/derecho.png" alt="">
            <div class="short_info">
              <h3 class="mrmago"><strong>Derecho</strong></h3>
              <!-- <div><span class="btn_1 rounded">Ir al curso</span></div> -->
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>

        ...

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Pero al quitarla de esa lista se quita para siempre ?

Comment: Salvo que guardes la regla en algún lado y luego la re apliques, no va a existir mas hasta que recargues el css o la pagina

Answer (score 0):

Pues no estoy seguro de haber entendido bien la pregunta pero 
creo que podrias usar la propiedad onclick="" para que cuando des el click llames a un evento o una funcion 
y en este evento o funcion JavaScript podrias tener el la propiedad classList que sirve para cambiar clases a tu codigo html

```
<form id="formulario">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Eviar mensaje" class="form-control" id="inputChat">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Eviar</button>
      </div>
    </form>

<script>formulario.classList = 'input-group  py-3 fixed-bottom container '</script>
```

En ejemplo anterior le estoy cambiando las clases a un formulario 
Espero que te ayude

Comment: Lo siento mucho soy muy nuevo